# Writing a number as string in ruby AXLSX library

Tags: ruby

I need to write a string like "001" as a string rather than a number so the value is shown as "001", not "1", in the output spreadsheet document. How is it possible using AXLSX library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you can format the string in ruby as mentioned using `rjust`. This will not help with the Excel file. In `axlsx` you can specify the data type when adding the row so that `axlsx` does not try and convert it for you e.g.

```
pkg = Axlsx::Package.new
wb = pkg.workbook
wb.add_worksheet do |sheet|  
  sheet.add_row ["001","001","001"], types: [:string,:integer,nil]
end
pkg.serialize('/test.xlsx')
```

This will produce a spreadsheet that looks like

```
|001|  1|  1|
```

**Note:** the third "001" was converted because I did not specify a type and `axlsx` decided it was a number using the below methodology in `Cell`.

```
def cell_type_from_value(v)
  if v.is_a?(Date)
    :date
  elsif v.is_a?(Time)
    :time
  elsif v.is_a?(TrueClass) || v.is_a?(FalseClass)
    :boolean
  elsif v.to_s =~ /\A[+-]?\d+?\Z/ #numeric
    :integer
  elsif v.to_s =~ /\A[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\Z/ #float
    :float
    # \A(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[0-1]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])
    # T(2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\.[0-9]+)?
    # (Z|[+-](?:2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):[0-5][0-9])?\Z
  elsif v.to_s =~/\A(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[0-1]|0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(\.[0-9]+)?(Z|[+-](?:2[0-3]|[0-1][0-9]):[0-5][0-9])?\Z/
    :iso_8601
  else
    :string
  end
end
```

Based on the result of this method it then "*casts*" the value using `to_i` in your case.